# Is Apache Thrift compatible with the QNX platform?

Tags: qt, thrift, qnx, blackberry-qnx

I have code that is running on Linux platform. I am trying to port it on QNX platform. Here I have used Apache Thrift libraries and for the same I am using QT widgets  so it will provide cross platform development. If anyone trying for same then please answer me if the Apache Thrift libraries are compatible with the QNX platform, and if yes, then how..?

Comment: QNX seems to offer a compatibility layer, so I could imagine that it works. Nevertheless, I have no experiences with QNX (main reason why I'm writing this as a comment) so I can only say that cross-platform communication is a primary goal of Apache Thrift and therefore we are interested in any contribution that helps making it work, if it doesn't already out of the box.

Comment: Since I was unable to find any compiled Apache Thrift libs for QNX my guess would be - not out of the box. Only viable option here seems compiling from source and seeing how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.If compiler and libs build, try the Test Suite next.